# New Browsers for Visual Studio Perfomance Testing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, load-testing

Does anybody know if there is an update to install new "browsers" for Visual Studio 2010 load testing?  2010 by default only has IE 7, 8, and old versions of chrome, safari, and firefox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In visual studio 2012 ?

Here is the list of all available browsers : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997561.aspx

You can add additional browsers by creating new .browser files. See here for more info http://davefancher.com/2011/05/18/vsts-2010-load-test-browser-definitions/